# Dict operation in loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have a dict as follows:

```
A[1]
Out[351]: [0, 4, 5, 6]
A[2]
Out[352]: [1, 25, 8, 4]
```

upto:

```
A[7]
Out[352]: [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Given these, I have to populate another dict using the following condition:

```
if A[1][0] <= A[2][0]:
    l=1
else:
    l=A[2][0]-A[1][2]/((A[1][1]-A[1][2])-(A[2][1]-A[2][0]))
```

which gives:

```
l
Out[354]: 1
```

Similarly:

```
if A[1][0] <= A[3][0]:
    l=1
else:
    l=A[3][0]-A[1][2]/((A[1][1]-A[1][2])-(A[3][1]-A[3][0]))
 if A[1][0] <= A[4][0]:
    l=1
else:
    l=A[4][0]-A[1][2]/((A[1][1]-A[1][2])-(A[4][1]-A[4][0]))
```

upto:

```
    if A[1][0] <= A[7][0]:
        l=1
    else:
       l=A[7][0]-A[1][2]/((A[1][1]-A[1][2])-(A[7][1]-A[7][0]))
```

If I append these, I'm supposed to get:

```
l
Out[360]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want the l to be a dict:

```
{1: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

for A1 and

```
{2: [some values]}
```

for A2..upto

```
{7: [some values]}
```

for A7.

One problem is I have to compute this starting from A[1][0], A[2][0] to A[1][0],A[7][0] and then for A[2][0], A[1]A[0]...so on upto A[7][0],A[6][0]. The other problem is that I need to skip the computation wherever A[i][0] and A[i][0] are to be compared. I've initially tried a loop like this:

```
i=[i for i in A.keys()]
k=[k for k in A.keys()]
while i != k:
        if A[i][0] <= A[k][0]:
             B=1
        else:
             B=A[k][0]-A[i][2]/((A[i][1]-A[i][2])-(A[k][1]-A[k][0]))

k +=1
i +=1
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-350-9d9e2d0e5d59>", line 8, in <module>
    k +=1

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Somebody kindly help me get the loop please. Please note that B has to be a dict.

Comment: `k=[k for k in CA.keys()]` - `k` is a list - what do you think `k += 1` should do?

Comment: I don't think that these are [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)s

Comment: You are trying to increment `k` by one, but `k` is not an `int`

Comment: first, k, i are lists, you can't +=1 to them. second what's CA? did you mean A? third, you should also check that you don't divide with 0

Comment: I  need to make sure i is not equal to k at all instances. K+=1 was something i tried first

Comment: Yes A.keys() sorry

Comment: Please stop downvoting people, not everybody can be exceptional coders. I thought this was a chance for us newbies to grow.

Comment: `i=[i for i in A.keys()]` is the same as `i = A.keys()` (py2) or as `i = list(A.keys())` (py3)

Comment: i=[i for i in A.keys()] gives me [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Comment: It looks like you're doing some kind of matrix operation. Perhaps turning your dict into a `pandas.DataFrame` will make things easier. If the operation you're trying to do has a name, it is likely a `numpy` or `scipy` function.

Comment: @DChy I'm a bit confused here. You're talking about dicts but you don't seem to have a single dict. Dicts are created either by the factory `dict()` or with curly brackets `{}`. Which you don't show in your code. Then, I don't understand what you're trying to do (the 3rd "dict"?).

Comment: wait I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I'm starting to understand your thing.

I would say the solution might look like something like this:

```
A = [
    [0, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 25, 8, 4],
    [0, 3, 6, 9],
]

D = {i: 1 if A[1][0] <= A[i][0] else A[i][0]-A[1][2]/((A[1][1]-A[1][2])-(A[i][1]-A[i][0])) for i in range(len(A))}

print D
# {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0}
```

I'll write a bit more details as to what I'm doing here. But first, I'm not 100% sure that's what you want as a result.

Comment: Actually, you want your dict values to be lists... so I realized once more that I'm not getting the stuff right.
You're saying at some point `l=1`, so you're assigning an int to `l`. You cannot expect it to become a `list` at some point.
In the output, you have a matrix. What is the formula for M[i,j] (I'm speaking in terms of maths, not of python). Once we get that figured out, we can translate it into python fairly easily. So, please express M[i,j] = f(A, i, j). :-)

Comment: is there a way for me to connect with you in a chat or something?

Comment: you're right my output will be in matrix terms. As for M[i,j] i will be 1,2..7 for A[1], A[2]..A[7]. J will also be the same except, m(i,j) for i=j (the diagonal elements) will be null.

Comment: Yes, I created a chatcrypt with groupname=SO48887198 and passwordname=SO48887198

Comment: I know that 0<=i<=3 and 0<=j<=6. And because it's not a square matrix, it won't have diagonals per-se. But I don't know what is the value of M[i,j] in terms of i and j.